# Debian GNOME: touchpad settings missing. Use libinput instead of synaptics

Tags: debian, gnome, libinput

I recently did a clean install of Debian GNOME and updated from stable to testing. Before updating to testing, I had several GUI settings for my touchpad. After updating, they are gone as shown in the screenshot: [image: Screenshot showing that options are missing]

For example, I would expect to find the setting for natural scrolling on this settings page.

Opening this page from the terminal yields the following error message

```
$ gnome-control-center mouse

(gnome-control-center:15084): mouse-cc-panel-WARNING **: Detected synaptics X driver, please migrate to libinput
```

which indicates that the problem is related to `libinput` not being installed.

Running `$ dpkg-query -l '*libinput*'` in the terminal shows that `libinput-bin`, `libinput10:amd64`, `libinput5:amd64` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` are installed.

[Arch Wiki - Touchpad Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Installation) says

> Please note that if you want desktop integration (i.e. ability to configure touchpad via GNOME control center or KDE settings), you need xf86-input-libinput.

The `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package, which is installed, is built from `xf86-input-libinput` referred to by Arch Wiki.

How can I solve my problem so that I get the missing settings back?

Comment: I had same issue for Ubuntu Gnome, it was solved with similar, see forum. [Missing touchpad settings in Gnome](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380313)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having had the same issue, I fixed it following this procedure:

- Install all libinput packages (libinput5, libinput10, xserver-xorg-input-
  libinput
- Remove the synaptics driver → xserver-xorg-input-synpatics
- Remove all synaptics related files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (Like `50-synaptics.conf`)
- Reboot

And the touchpad is back in gcontrol-center.

#### Cause of the problem:

GNOME and most other desktop environments depended on the old "synaptic" drivers for touchpads. However, in GNOME 3.20, they have switched to libinput. The problem was because "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" is a dependency of "xserver-xorg-input-all".

Source : https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/07/msg00266.html

Comment: Since I already had the `libinput-bin`, `libinput10:amd64`, `libinput5:amd64` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` packages installed, I just needed to remove synaptics and the configuration files so I just ran `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Now it works!

Comment: This answer is fine as far as it goes; however the Synaptics driver provided a great variety of options through the `synclient` command line tool, and while some settings are available through `xinput`, `xinput --list-props` / `xinput --set-prop` and `xinput --get-button-map` / `xinput --set-button-map`, with a "`SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`" in particular, there is not an apparent way to enable two-finger tapping as was available through `synclient`.